# Display GPS module data to my TFT display

Tags: arduino-mega, c, gps, debugging, tft

1. I am using Arduino Mega 2560 and I have written code for my GPS module (Neo-6m-0-001/GY-NEO6MV2) and it is working fine independently.
2. I also have written code for Compass module (QMC5883L) which is also working fine independently and I am displaying the direction on my TFT (made a graphical compass dial on TFT) in real-time which is also working fine and needle varies according to my compass direction.
3. Now I am trying to combine both codes and display the long. and lat. values in graphical TFT fields but it is giving me error.

**GPS code**

```
//Connect with pin 18 and 19
#include <TinyGPS.h>
float lat,lon;
TinyGPS gps; // create gps object

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(57600); // connect serial
    Serial.println("The GPS Received Signal:");
    Serial1.begin(9600); // connect gps sensor

}

void loop(){
    while(Serial1.available()){ // check for gps data
    if(gps.encode(Serial1.read()))// encode gps data
    { 
    gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lon); // get latitude and longitude

    Serial.print("Position: ");

    //Latitude
    Serial.print("Latitude: ");
    Serial.print(lat,6);
    Serial.print(",");

    //Longitude
    Serial.print("Longitude: ");
    Serial.println(lon,6); 

   }
  }
}
```

**TFT and Compass Code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>      // this is needed even tho we aren't using it
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_ILI9341.h"
#include <Adafruit_STMPE610.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

void Draw_Compass_Rose();
void display_item(int x, int y, String token, int txt_colour, int txt_size);
void arrow(int x2, int y2, int x1, int y1, int alength, int awidth, int colour);

// For the Adafruit TFT shield, these are the default.
#define TFT_DC 9
#define TFT_CS 10

// Use hardware SPI (on Uno, #13, #12, #11) and the above for CS/DC
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);

// The STMPE610 uses hardware SPI on the shield, and #8
#define STMPE_CS 8
Adafruit_STMPE610 ts = Adafruit_STMPE610(STMPE_CS);

// This is calibration data for the raw touch data to the screen coordinates
#define TS_MINX 150
#define TS_MINY 130
#define TS_MAXX 3800
#define TS_MAXY 4000

/*** UI details */
#define BUTTON_X 40
#define BUTTON_Y 140
#define BUTTON_W 60
#define BUTTON_H 30
#define BUTTON_SPACING_X 20
#define BUTTON_SPACING_Y 10
#define BUTTON_TEXTSIZE 2

/* Back Button details */
#define BACK_BUTTON_X 40
#define BACK_BUTTON_Y 40

#define BLACK   0x0000
#define BLUE    0x001F
#define RED     0xF800
#define GREEN   0x07E0
#define CYAN    0x07FF
#define MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define WHITE   0xFFFF

// text box where numbers go,position the text box/rectangle
#define TEXT_X 10
#define TEXT_Y 10
#define TEXT_X1 10
#define TEXT_Y1 50
#define TEXT_X2 10
#define TEXT_Y2 90
#define TEXT_W 220
#define TEXT_H 30
#define TEXT_TSIZE 3
#define TEXT_TCOLOR ILI9341_MAGENTA
// the data (phone #) we store in the textfield
#define TEXT_LEN 12
char latitude[TEXT_LEN+1] = "";
char longitude[TEXT_LEN+1] = "";
uint8_t latitude_i=0;
uint8_t longitude_i=0;
char STATUS_X;
char STATUS_Y;
float lat = 0.0;
float lon = 0.0;
float AZMTH = 0.0;
float add;

const int centreX  = 160;
const int centreY  = 120;
const int diameter = 100;
int last_dx, last_dy, dx, dy;

// 0 -> Keypad    1 -> Compass
unsigned int page_state = 0;

// 0 -> latitude     1 -> longitude
unsigned int cursor_state = 0;

/* create 15 buttons, in classic candybar phone style */
char buttonlabels[15][5] = {"ENT", "CLR", "NEXT", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", ">"};
uint16_t buttoncolors[15] = {ILI9341_DARKGREEN, ILI9341_DARKGREY, ILI9341_RED, 
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, 
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, 
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE,
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_ORANGE};
Adafruit_GFX_Button buttons[15];

char backButtonLable[1][5] = {"Back"};
uint16_t backButtonColors[1] = {ILI9341_DARKGREEN};
Adafruit_GFX_Button backButton[1];

// Print something in the mini status bar with either flashstring
void status(const __FlashStringHelper *msg) {
  tft.fillRect(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y, 240, 8, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);//font size on top of white box
  tft.print(msg);
}
// or charstring
void status(char *msg) {
  tft.fillRect(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y, 240, 8, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);//font size on top of white box
  tft.print(msg);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Arduin-Test-LCD"); 

  // clear the screen
  tft.begin();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_MAGENTA);
  tft.print("      WELCOME TO AZIMUTH SYSTEM");
  // eep touchscreen not found?
  if (!ts.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't start touchscreen controller");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Touchscreen started");

  // create buttons
  for (uint8_t row=0; row<5; row++) {
    for (uint8_t col=0; col<3; col++) {
      buttons[col + row*3].initButton(&tft, BUTTON_X+col*(BUTTON_W+BUTTON_SPACING_X), 
                 BUTTON_Y+row*(BUTTON_H+BUTTON_SPACING_Y),    // x, y, w, h, outline, fill, text
                  BUTTON_W, BUTTON_H, ILI9341_WHITE, buttoncolors[col+row*3], ILI9341_WHITE,
                  buttonlabels[col + row*3], BUTTON_TEXTSIZE); 
      buttons[col + row*3].drawButton();
    }
  }

  // create 'text field'
  tft.drawRect(TEXT_X, TEXT_Y, TEXT_W, TEXT_H, ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.drawRect(TEXT_X1, TEXT_Y1, TEXT_W, TEXT_H, ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.drawRect(TEXT_X2, TEXT_Y2, TEXT_W, TEXT_H, ILI9341_WHITE);

  tft.setCursor(TEXT_X+2, TEXT_Y+10);
  tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
  tft.print(" LAT:");

  tft.setCursor(TEXT_X1 + 2, TEXT_Y1+10);
  tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
  tft.print(" LONG:");

  tft.setCursor(TEXT_X2 + 2, TEXT_Y2+10);
  tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
  tft.print(" AZMTH:");
}

void loop() {
  TS_Point p;

  if (ts.bufferSize()) {
    p = ts.getPoint(); 
  } else {
    // this is our way of tracking touch 'release'!
    p.x = p.y = p.z = -1;
  }

  // Scale from ~0->4000 to tft.width using the calibration #'s
  if (p.z != -1) {
    p.x = map(p.x, TS_MINX, TS_MAXX, 0, tft.width());
    p.y = map(p.y, TS_MINY, TS_MAXY, 0, tft.height());
    Serial.print("("); Serial.print(p.x); Serial.print(", "); 
    Serial.print(p.y); Serial.print(", "); 
    Serial.print(p.z); Serial.println(") ");
  }

  switch(page_state){
    case 0: // Means Keypad
  // go thru all the buttons, checking if they were pressed
  for (uint8_t b=0; b<15; b++) {
    if (buttons[b].contains(p.x, p.y)) {
      //Serial.print("Pressing: "); Serial.println(b);
      buttons[b].press(true);  // tell the button it is pressed
    } else {
      buttons[b].press(false);  // tell the button it is NOT pressed
    }
  }

  // now we can ask the buttons if their state has changed
  for (uint8_t b=0; b<15; b++) {
    if (buttons[b].justReleased()) {
      // Serial.print("Released: "); Serial.println(b);
      buttons[b].drawButton();  // draw normal
    }

    if (buttons[b].justPressed()) {
        buttons[b].drawButton(true);  // draw invert!    

        // ENT Button was clicked
        if (b == 0){
          lon = atof(longitude);
          lat = atof(latitude);
          status(F("  Searching and laser start rotating"));
          Serial.println("Searching ");
          Serial.print("Latitude : ");
          Serial.println(String(lat));
          Serial.print("longitude : ");
          Serial.println(String(lon));
          Serial.print("lat + lon = ");
          AZMTH=lat+lon;
          Serial.println(AZMTH);

            // just add this part in this location
          //----- AND REPLACE THE VALUE -----
          tft.setCursor(TEXT_X2 + 90, TEXT_Y2+10);
              tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
              tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
              tft.print(AZMTH);
              Serial.print(AZMTH);

        }

        // CLR Button was clicked
        else if (b == 1) {
          switch(cursor_state){
            case 0:
              if (latitude > 0) {
                latitude_i--;
                latitude[latitude_i] = ' ';
              }
              break;

            case 1:
              if (longitude > 0) {
                longitude_i--;
                longitude[longitude_i] = ' ';
              }
              break;
          }
        }

        // NEXT Button was clicked
        else if (b == 2){
          page_state = 1;
          tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
          latitude[0]=0x00;
          latitude_i=0;
          longitude[0]=0x00;
          longitude_i=0;
          cursor_state = 0;

          tft.setRotation(1);
          Draw_Compass_Rose();
            double angle= 270; //use heading from compass
            dx = (diameter * cos((angle-90)*3.14/180)) + centreX;    // calculate X position
            dy = (diameter * sin((angle-90)*3.14/180)) + centreY;    // calculate Y position
            arrow(last_dx,last_dy, centreX, centreY, 20, 20,BLACK);  // Erase last arrow     
            arrow(dx,dy, centreX, centreY, 20, 20,CYAN);             // Draw arrow in new position
            last_dx = dx;
            last_dy = dy;
          delay(25);
          tft.setRotation(0);

          }          

        // '>' Button was clicked 
        else if (b == 14){
          /* Toggle between latitude and longitude */
          if (cursor_state == 0){
            cursor_state = 1;
          } else if (cursor_state == 1){
            cursor_state = 0;
          }
        }

        // if a numberpad button, append the relevant # to the textfield
        else if (b >= 3) {
          switch(cursor_state){
            case 0:
              if (latitude_i < TEXT_LEN) {
                latitude[latitude_i] = buttonlabels[b][0];
                latitude_i++;
                latitude[latitude_i] = 0; // zero terminate
                //fona.playDTMF(buttonlabels[b][0]);
              }
              break;
            case 1:
              if (longitude_i < TEXT_LEN) {
                longitude[longitude_i] = buttonlabels[b][0];
                longitude_i++;
                longitude[longitude_i] = 0; // zero terminate
                //fona.playDTMF(buttonlabels[b][0]);
              }
              break;
          }

        }

      switch(cursor_state){
            case 0:
              // update the current latitude
              tft.setCursor(TEXT_X + 90, TEXT_Y+10);//set position of text when user key in the lat angle
              tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
              tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
              tft.print(latitude);
              Serial.print(latitude);
              break;

              // update the current longitude
            case 1:
              tft.setCursor(TEXT_X1 + 90, TEXT_Y1+10);//set position of text when user key in the long angle
              tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
              tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
              tft.print(longitude);
              Serial.print(longitude);
              break;
          }

    } 
//        
      delay(50); // UI debouncing

     }
   }
}

void display_item(int x, int y, String token, int txt_colour, int txt_size) {
    tft.setCursor(x, y);
    tft.setTextColor(txt_colour);
    tft.setTextSize(txt_size);
    tft.print(token);
    tft.setTextSize(2); // Back to default text size
}

void arrow(int x2, int y2, int x1, int y1, int alength, int awidth, int colour) {
  float distance;
  int dx, dy, x2o,y2o,x3,y3,x4,y4,k;
    distance = sqrt(pow((x1 - x2),2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    dx = x2 + (x1 - x2) * alength / distance;
    dy = y2 + (y1 - y2) * alength / distance;
    k = awidth / alength;
    x2o = x2 - dx;
    y2o = dy - y2;
    x3 = y2o * k + dx;
    y3 = x2o * k + dy;
    x4 = dx - y2o * k;
    y4 = dy - x2o * k;
    tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x1, y1, dx, dy, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x3, y3, x4, y4, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x3, y3, x2, y2, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x2, y2, x4, y4, colour);
}
void Draw_Compass_Rose(){
  int dxo, dyo, dxi, dyi;           
    tft.drawCircle(centreX,centreY,diameter,YELLOW);  // Draw compass circle
  for (float i = 0; i <360; i = i + 22.5) {
    dxo = diameter * cos((i-90)*3.14/180);
    dyo = diameter * sin((i-90)*3.14/180);
    dxi = dxo * 0.9;
    dyi = dyo * 0.9;
    tft.drawLine(dxi+centreX,dyi+centreY,dxo+centreX,dyo+centreY,YELLOW);  
  }
    display_item((centreX-5),(centreY-85),"N",RED,2);
    display_item((centreX-5),(centreY+70),"S",RED,2);
    display_item((centreX+80),(centreY-5),"E",RED,2);
    display_item((centreX-85),(centreY-5),"W",RED,2);
}
```

**Combine Code**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>      // this is needed even tho we aren't using it
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_ILI9341.h"
#include <Adafruit_STMPE610.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <TinyGPS.h>

TinyGPS gps; // create gps 

void Draw_Compass_Rose();
void display_item(int x, int y, String token, int txt_colour, int txt_size);
void arrow(int x2, int y2, int x1, int y1, int alength, int awidth, int colour);

// For the Adafruit TFT shield, these are the default.
#define TFT_DC 9
#define TFT_CS 10

// Use hardware SPI (on Uno, #13, #12, #11) and the above for CS/DC
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);

// The STMPE610 uses hardware SPI on the shield, and #8
#define STMPE_CS 8
Adafruit_STMPE610 ts = Adafruit_STMPE610(STMPE_CS);

// This is calibration data for the raw touch data to the screen coordinates
#define TS_MINX 150
#define TS_MINY 130
#define TS_MAXX 3800
#define TS_MAXY 4000

/*** UI details */
#define BUTTON_X 40
#define BUTTON_Y 140
#define BUTTON_W 60
#define BUTTON_H 30
#define BUTTON_SPACING_X 20
#define BUTTON_SPACING_Y 10
#define BUTTON_TEXTSIZE 2

/* Back Button details */
#define BACK_BUTTON_X 40
#define BACK_BUTTON_Y 40

#define BLACK   0x0000
#define BLUE    0x001F
#define RED     0xF800
#define GREEN   0x07E0
#define CYAN    0x07FF
#define MAGENTA 0xF81F
#define YELLOW  0xFFE0
#define WHITE   0xFFFF

// text box where numbers go,position the text box/rectangle
#define TEXT_X 10
#define TEXT_Y 10
#define TEXT_X1 10
#define TEXT_Y1 50
#define TEXT_X2 10
#define TEXT_Y2 90
#define TEXT_W 220
#define TEXT_H 30
#define TEXT_TSIZE 3
#define TEXT_TCOLOR ILI9341_MAGENTA
// the data (phone #) we store in the textfield
#define TEXT_LEN 12
char latitude[TEXT_LEN+1] = "";
char longitude[TEXT_LEN+1] = "";
uint8_t latitude_i=0;
uint8_t longitude_i=0;
char STATUS_X;
char STATUS_Y;
float lat = 0.0;
float lng = 0.0;
float AZMTH = 0.0;
float add;

const int centreX  = 160;
const int centreY  = 120;
const int diameter = 100;
int last_dx, last_dy, dx, dy;

// 0 -> Keypad    1 -> Compass
unsigned int page_state = 0;

// 0 -> latitude     1 -> longitude
unsigned int cursor_state = 0;

/* create 15 buttons, in classic candybar phone style */
char buttonlabels[15][5] = {"ENT", "CLR", "NEXT", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", ".", ">"};
uint16_t buttoncolors[15] = {ILI9341_DARKGREEN, ILI9341_DARKGREY, ILI9341_RED, 
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, 
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, 
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE,
                             ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_BLUE, ILI9341_ORANGE};
Adafruit_GFX_Button buttons[15];

char backButtonLable[1][5] = {"Back"};
uint16_t backButtonColors[1] = {ILI9341_DARKGREEN};
Adafruit_GFX_Button backButton[1];

// Print something in the mini status bar with either flashstring
void status(const __FlashStringHelper *msg) {
  tft.fillRect(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y, 240, 8, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);//font size on top of white box
  tft.print(msg);
}
// or charstring
void status(char *msg) {
  tft.fillRect(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y, 240, 8, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(STATUS_X, STATUS_Y);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(1);//font size on top of white box
  tft.print(msg);
}

void setup() {
Serial.begin(57600); // connect serial
Serial.println("The GPS Received Signal:");
Serial1.begin(9600); // connect gps sensor

  // clear the screen
  tft.begin();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_MAGENTA);
  tft.print("      WELCOME TO AZIMUTH SYSTEM");
  // eep touchscreen not found?
  if (!ts.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't start touchscreen controller");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Touchscreen started");

  // create buttons
  for (uint8_t row=0; row<5; row++) {
    for (uint8_t col=0; col<3; col++) {
      buttons[col + row*3].initButton(&tft, BUTTON_X+col*(BUTTON_W+BUTTON_SPACING_X), 
                 BUTTON_Y+row*(BUTTON_H+BUTTON_SPACING_Y),    // x, y, w, h, outline, fill, text
                  BUTTON_W, BUTTON_H, ILI9341_WHITE, buttoncolors[col+row*3], ILI9341_WHITE,
                  buttonlabels[col + row*3], BUTTON_TEXTSIZE); 
      buttons[col + row*3].drawButton();
    }
  }

  // create 'text field'
  tft.drawRect(TEXT_X, TEXT_Y, TEXT_W, TEXT_H, ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.drawRect(TEXT_X1, TEXT_Y1, TEXT_W, TEXT_H, ILI9341_WHITE);
  tft.drawRect(TEXT_X2, TEXT_Y2, TEXT_W, TEXT_H, ILI9341_WHITE);

  tft.setCursor(TEXT_X+2, TEXT_Y+10);
  tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
  tft.print(" LAT:");

  tft.setCursor(TEXT_X1 + 2, TEXT_Y1+10);
  tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
  tft.print(" LONG:");

  tft.setCursor(TEXT_X2 + 2, TEXT_Y2+10);
  tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
  tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
  tft.print(" AZMTH:");
}

void loop() {
  TS_Point p;
  while(Serial1.available()){ // check for gps data
  if(gps.encode(Serial1.read()))// encode gps data
   Serial.print("Position: ");
  }
  if (ts.bufferSize()) {
    p = ts.getPoint(); 
  } else {
    // this is our way of tracking touch 'release'!
    p.x = p.y = p.z = -1;
  }

  // Scale from ~0->4000 to tft.width using the calibration #'s
  if (p.z != -1) {
    p.x = map(p.x, TS_MINX, TS_MAXX, 0, tft.width());
    p.y = map(p.y, TS_MINY, TS_MAXY, 0, tft.height());
    Serial.print("("); Serial.print(p.x); Serial.print(", "); 
    Serial.print(p.y); Serial.print(", "); 
    Serial.print(p.z); Serial.println(") ");
  }

  switch(page_state){
    case 0: // Means Keypad
  // go thru all the buttons, checking if they were pressed
  for (uint8_t b=0; b<15; b++) {
    if (buttons[b].contains(p.x, p.y)) {
      //Serial.print("Pressing: "); Serial.println(b);
      buttons[b].press(true);  // tell the button it is pressed
    } else {
      buttons[b].press(false);  // tell the button it is NOT pressed
    }
  }

  // now we can ask the buttons if their state has changed
  for (uint8_t b=0; b<15; b++) {
    if (buttons[b].justReleased()) {
      // Serial.print("Released: "); Serial.println(b);
      buttons[b].drawButton();  // draw normal
    }

    if (buttons[b].justPressed()) {
        buttons[b].drawButton(true);  // draw invert!    

        // ENT Button was clicked
        if (b == 0){
          lng = atof(longitude);
          lat = atof(latitude);
          status(F("  Searching and laser start rotating"));
          Serial.println("Searching ");
          Serial.print("Latitude : ");
          Serial.println(String(lat));
          Serial.print("longitude : ");
          Serial.println(String(lng));
          Serial.print("lat + lng = ");
          AZMTH=lat+lng;
          Serial.println(AZMTH);

            // just add this part in this location
          //----- AND REPLACE THE VALUE -----
          tft.setCursor(TEXT_X2 + 90, TEXT_Y2+10);
              tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
              tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
              tft.print(AZMTH);
              Serial.print(AZMTH);

        }

        // CLR Button was clicked
        else if (b == 1) {
          switch(cursor_state){
            case 0:
              if (latitude > 0) {
                latitude_i--;
                latitude[latitude_i] = ' ';
              }
              break;

            case 1:
              if (longitude > 0) {
                longitude_i--;
                longitude[longitude_i] = ' ';
              }
              break;
          }
        }

        // NEXT Button was clicked
        else if (b == 2){
          page_state = 1;
          tft.fillScreen(BLACK);
          latitude[0]=0x00;
          latitude_i=0;
          longitude[0]=0x00;
          longitude_i=0;
          cursor_state = 0;

          tft.setRotation(1);
          Draw_Compass_Rose();
            double angle= 270; //use heading from compass
            dx = (diameter * cos((angle-90)*3.14/180)) + centreX;    // calculate X position
            dy = (diameter * sin((angle-90)*3.14/180)) + centreY;    // calculate Y position
            arrow(last_dx,last_dy, centreX, centreY, 20, 20,BLACK);  // Erase last arrow     
            arrow(dx,dy, centreX, centreY, 20, 20,CYAN);             // Draw arrow in new position
            last_dx = dx;
            last_dy = dy;
          delay(25);
          tft.setRotation(0);

          }          

        // '>' Button was clicked 
        else if (b == 14){
          /* Toggle between latitude and longitude */
          if (cursor_state == 0){
            cursor_state = 1;
          } else if (cursor_state == 1){
            cursor_state = 0;
          }
        }

        // if a numberpad button, append the relevant # to the textfield
        else if (b >= 3) {
          switch(cursor_state){
            case 0:
              if (latitude_i < TEXT_LEN) {
                latitude[latitude_i] = buttonlabels[b][0];
                latitude_i++;
                latitude[latitude_i] = 0; // zero terminate
                //fona.playDTMF(buttonlabels[b][0]);
              }
              break;
            case 1:
              if (longitude_i < TEXT_LEN) {
                longitude[longitude_i] = buttonlabels[b][0];
                longitude_i++;
                longitude[longitude_i] = 0; // zero terminate
                //fona.playDTMF(buttonlabels[b][0]);
              }
              break;
          }

        }

      switch(cursor_state){
            case 0:
              // update the current latitude
              tft.setCursor(TEXT_X + 90, TEXT_Y+10);//set position of text when user key in the lat angle
              tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
              tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
              Serial.print(latitude);
              if (gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lng))
              {
              tft.print(String(gps.f_get_position(&lat));
              double lat=gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lng));
              Serial.print(lat, 6);  
              }
              break;

              // update the current longitude
            case 1:
              tft.setCursor(TEXT_X1 + 90, TEXT_Y1+10);//set position of text when user key in the long angle
              tft.setTextColor(TEXT_TCOLOR, ILI9341_BLACK);
              tft.setTextSize(2);//font size inside white box
              Serial.print(longitude);
              if (gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lng))
              {
              tft.print(String(gps.f_get_position(&lng));
              double lng=gps.f_get_position(&lat,&lng));
              Serial.print(lng, 6);  
              }
              break;
          }

    } 
//        
      delay(50); // UI debouncing

     }
   }
}

void display_item(int x, int y, String token, int txt_colour, int txt_size) {
    tft.setCursor(x, y);
    tft.setTextColor(txt_colour);
    tft.setTextSize(txt_size);
    tft.print(token);
    tft.setTextSize(2); // Back to default text size
}

void arrow(int x2, int y2, int x1, int y1, int alength, int awidth, int colour) {
  float distance;
  int dx, dy, x2o,y2o,x3,y3,x4,y4,k;
    distance = sqrt(pow((x1 - x2),2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    dx = x2 + (x1 - x2) * alength / distance;
    dy = y2 + (y1 - y2) * alength / distance;
    k = awidth / alength;
    x2o = x2 - dx;
    y2o = dy - y2;
    x3 = y2o * k + dx;
    y3 = x2o * k + dy;
    x4 = dx - y2o * k;
    y4 = dy - x2o * k;
    tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x1, y1, dx, dy, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x3, y3, x4, y4, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x3, y3, x2, y2, colour);
    tft.drawLine(x2, y2, x4, y4, colour);
}
void Draw_Compass_Rose(){
  int dxo, dyo, dxi, dyi;           
    tft.drawCircle(centreX,centreY,diameter,YELLOW);  // Draw compass circle
  for (float i = 0; i <360; i = i + 22.5) {
    dxo = diameter * cos((i-90)*3.14/180);
    dyo = diameter * sin((i-90)*3.14/180);
    dxi = dxo * 0.9;
    dyi = dyo * 0.9;
    tft.drawLine(dxi+centreX,dyi+centreY,dxo+centreX,dyo+centreY,YELLOW);  
  }
    display_item((centreX-5),(centreY-85),"N",RED,2);
    display_item((centreX-5),(centreY+70),"S",RED,2);
    display_item((centreX+80),(centreY-5),"E",RED,2);
    display_item((centreX-85),(centreY-5),"W",RED,2);
}
```

Attached is the image of error line, GUI on TFT with lat. and long. field, TFT, and log errors.
[Errror line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPMg2.jpg)

[image: GUI]

[image: TFT]

[image: error line]

[image: log error]

[image: 1]

Comment: Please do not include images of errors but include the full text. So, read what the error message says: "could not convert from 'void' to 'bool' ".... This gives a massive clue. You cannot use the output of `gps.f_get_position(...)`, which is a `void`, inside an `if` statement, which expects something it can evaluate to a `bool` (i.e. a "true" or "false") to base its decision on.